# How do I invoke Lambda function across all AWS regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the below lambda function which stops all the Ec-2 instances with the AutoOff_uat tag. If I want to run this lambda across two regions us-east-1 and us-east-2. what modifications do i need to make

```
import boto3
import logging

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#define the connection
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')



def lambda_handler(event, context):
# Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
# all running EC2 instances.
filters = [{
        'Name': 'tag:AutoOff_uat',
        'Values': ['True']
    },
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
        'Values': ['running']
    }
]

#filter the instances
instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

#locate all running instances
RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

#print the instances for logging purposes
#print RunningInstances 

#make sure there are actually instances to shut down. 
if len(RunningInstances) > 0:
    #perform the shutdown
    shuttingDown = ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=RunningInstances).stop()
    print shuttingDown
else:
    print "Nothing to see here"
```

Comment: May be worth investigating [Systems Manager Automation](https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/features/#Automation).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the region to the resource when you create it

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2')
```

I would recommend wrapping all of your code in a function which takes the region as an argument and then iterate over a list of regions you want to operate on.

```
import boto3
import logging

#setup simple logging for INFO
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def shutdown_instances(region):
    #define the connection
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region=region)

    # Use the filter() method of the instances collection to retrieve
    # all running EC2 instances.
    filters = [{
            'Name': 'tag:AutoOff_uat',
            'Values': ['True']
        },
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name', 
            'Values': ['running']
        }
    ]

    #filter the instances
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    #locate all running instances
    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    #print the instances for logging purposes
    #print RunningInstances 

    #make sure there are actually instances to shut down. 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for region in ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2']:
        shutdown_instances(region)
```

Comment: but when i put multiple regions in argument like
    
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-2', 'us-east-1')

it does not work

Comment: You cannot specify multiple regions. See my code example above